# How do I make an absolutely positioned element only use the necessary amount of width?

Tags: html, css

So I'm putting together some alert system for a website I'm building. Layout is pretty simple:

```
<style>
     #alert{
         position:absolute;
         padding:10px;
         display:table;
         margin:0 auto;
     }
</style>
<div id="alert">
    Hey user, I have a very important message for you.
</alert>
```

Now, if an element isn't absolutely positioned I normally use `display:table` to make sure it only takes the necessary amount of width, but absolutely positioning it kind of ruins that.

Is there a way to make it so that the element only takes the necessary amount of width, but still be absolutely positioned?

**EDIT**:
Basically what I am looking for is an absolutely positioned element that has dynamic width, and is centered.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the broken layout.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sightofnick/rwauA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
<style>
    #alert {
         position:absolute;
         width:100%; /* Keep in mind this is for an entire page */
         height: 16px; /* Match the font-size of the alert */
         text-align:center;
         cursor:pointer;
    }
    #alert #inner_alert {
         display:inline-block;
         padding:10px;
    }
</style>
<div id="alert">
    <div id="inner_alert">Here is the message!</div>
</div>
```

This will produce a centered element that will only be as wide as it needs to be and is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can used `left` or `right` properties as like this

```
#alert{
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

hey now you can define your value in `left right top bottom` as according your layouts

if you define `position absolute` than define your div `width or height`

now you can used this one live demo http://jsfiddle.net/YvMAJ/